# XsltListViewWebPart with CrossList

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

i'm new to SharePoint, and i'm working with sharepoint 2010.

I'm trying to create a webpart on SPdesigner that holds a XsltListViewWebPart
which is linked to a custom library i created in the Site Collection.

I want to list all the documents related to current user from the all sites
under the site collection.

to do so i set the DataSourceMode from "List"  to "CrossList"
but then the webpart doesn't show any document as seen in the image below
(its like there is a line but the data is not showing..)

[image]

Does any one know what the reason for this?

How can I fix it to work so the webpart will list all docs from all sites in collection?

Answer (score 0):

First, is there any reason why you don't use the out of the box Relevant Documents Web Part?

I don't think the xslt List View Web Part works in crosslist mode. What you'll need to do is use a Data View Web Part.

Comment: Hi, yes there is a reason, i want to show a set of columns which at least one of them comes from the template of my custom library, and this can't be done with Relevant Documents Web Part.. (check out this link [link](http://www.manliane.com/kb/142/).   When i choose to insert a data view i choose my custom library which then creates a xslt list view web part..